# best way to deploy a Wolfram Language program on a machine without its own Mathematica license?

Tags: cdf-format, wolfram-cloud, email

I have written a small program that accepts a string as input and returns a List of graphical images as output. A simple example is shown below.

How best to deploy this on a machine without a Mathematica license? I think CDF is not a option because the code accepts an arbitrary string as input. My experimentation with deploying on the cloud and MailReceiverFunction has led only to errors and scrambled output. I am open to any suggestions.

Here is a trivial example

```
demo[in_String] := Module[{pic},
  pic = xxxx;
  Table[pic, {StringLength[in]}]
  ]
```

Where the xxxx is a Graphics image. In Mathematica, it looks like this:

[image: code that works on the desktop]

The code works as intended on the desktop, so

```
demo["test"]
```

returns

[image: a List of Graphics]

And integrating it with `FormPage` works as intended as well, so long as I stay on the local machine.

```
FormPage["inString" -> String, demo[#inString] &]
```

[image: a working Form-based interface]

My goal is to be able to access this from another machine, so I deploy to the web, with

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage["inString" -> String, demo[#inString] &]]
```

But this doesn't work. Instead of returning a list of Graphics, I get

```
{ " class="img-responsive"/> " class="img-responsive"/> " class="img-responsive"/>
```

And with slightly more elaborate examples, pages of text that look like some kind of ASCII-based encoding of the graphics images. In any case, certainly not the graphics themselves.

Help?

Comment: As I understand the question you have a node with a Mathematica license (perhaps in the cloud), a node without a Mathematica license, and from the node without a license you want (either by a browser or email) to remotely execute code on the node with the license. Correct?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock I have code running on a desktop machine that has a license; the same code may be deployable to the cloud, I'm not sure. I would like to submit input (a string) to the software from a machine that doesn't have a Mathematica license, and to receive the output on that machine. Could be via a webpage, e-mail, or other mechanism. Does that help?

Comment: The `APIFunction` and `CloudDeploy` feature might be what you are looking for [see the example in the documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html)

Comment: The approach @Sascha mentions, or [FormFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html) or [FormPage](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormPage.html), can run your code in the cloud on the Wolfram Development Platform, which can be accessed from any browser. If you want to do the same thing, but with the code running on your own licensed machine, then you could set up a private cloud on this machine.

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock  have tried several of these approaches, including CloudDeploy@FormPage, which would seem to do exactly what I want, but instead of outputting a list of graphics, it outputs long strings of random characters with occasional tags like `class="img-responsive"/> `

Comment: If you could edit your question to exhibit the _minimal_ FormPage code that demonstrates the error, I suspect someone will provide an answer that sets you on the right path.

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock OK, detailed example provided.

Comment: The FormPage function need not be limited to a single graphic output. It can pretty much output anything that could be displayed on a webpage. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock actually, one graphicsgrid is perfect for this application. Is there anyway to have controls other than textfields at the top?

Comment: FormPage can have pretty much any kind of control, for examples see [FormObject](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormObject.html) > Examples > Scope > Controls documentation section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the simplest case the FormPage function would return a graphic:

```
CloudDeploy[
   FormPage["inString" -> "String",
      GraphicsGrid[{
         Table[
            Image[
               Graphics[{Disk[{0,0}, Sqrt[2]], Red, Disk[]}], ImageSize -> 32],
            {StringLength[#inString]}
         ]
       }] &
   ],
   FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory,"FormPageDemo"}]]
```

[image]